# AWS DMS: Unable to See RDS Instances from Multiple AWS Accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-dms, dms

I'm currently facing an issue with AWS Database Migration Service (DMS) across multiple AWS accounts. My goal is to use my RDS instances as source endpoints and create new RDS instances from them. However, I've encountered a problem where the RDS instances are not visible in the source endpoint configuration, except for one specific AWS account.

I would appreciate any guidance or insights into why the RDS instances are not visible in AWS DMS from most of my AWS accounts. If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has suggestions for troubleshooting steps, please share your expertise.

- Configuration Steps: I've followed the standard steps to configure the source and target endpoints. However, when attempting to use an RDS instance as a source, the list is empty.
- Error Messages: No specific error messages are displayed, and the list is just empty.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to specify an RDS instance as a source endpoint, it explicitly tells you in the console;

> Instances available only for current user and region

If you want to migrate your databases cross-account or cross-region, you'll need to create a migration instance profile in the VPC of either source or target RDS, and set up connectivity between these VPCs using peering.